# Configuring Tomcat Connection Pooling without using JNDI

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am new to the connection pooling technique and in the Tomcat Official Guide for The Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool, there is an option to initialize pooling by Plain Java Class, by initializing Data Source class. But when I try to implement the same, it is giving me below exception all the time. My url is correct.

```
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
```

Can some one help to understand what all required to setup Connection Pooling using Pool Properties ?

```
String dburl="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname) (PORT=1521))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=shostname2)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=Service)))";

 p.setUrl(dburl);
p.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
p.setUsername(username);
p.setPassword(pwd);
p.setJmxEnabled(true);
p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1 from dual");
p.setTestOnReturn(false);
p.setValidationInterval(30000);
p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
p.setMaxActive(100);
p.setInitialSize(10);
p.setMaxWait(10000);
p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(600);
p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
p.setMinIdle(10);
p.setLogAbandoned(true);

p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
p.setJdbcInterceptors(
        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;"
        + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer;"
        + "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ResetAbandonedTimer");

p.setLogValidationErrors(true);   datasource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource(  );
datasource.setPoolProperties(p); 



Jul 17, 2017 1:47:58 PM org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool init
SEVERE: Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: invalid arguments in call
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.check_error(DBError.java:1160)
    at oracle.jdbc.ttc7.TTC7Protocol.logon(TTC7Protocol.java:183)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleConnection.<init>(OracleConnection.java:346)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.getConnectionInstance(OracleDriver.java:468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:314)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:732)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:664)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:479)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131)
    at org.telstra.ipdam.utils.DatasourceConnection.getConnection(DatasourceConnection.java:29)
    at org.telstra.ipdam.persistence.Service.getEnrichmentDetails(Service.java:50)
    at org.telstra.ipdam.enrichmentResource.EnrichmentUpdate.getEnrichmentMessage(EnrichmentUpdate.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please put full stacktrace

Comment: Please don't repost questions. If you need to draw attention to it, you need to add more information to the original question.

Comment: This question is tagged with, and full of, [tag:jndi]. What therefore is the meaning of 'without using JNDI' in your title?

Answer (score -1):

this issue  occurring due to `oracle.jdbc` driver you can try  `p.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");` in place of `p.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");`

Comment: I tried this,but didn't work. Still throwing the same error.

Comment: If this was the problem he wouldn't have got as far as he did.